# Import Django settings from app into project settings?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, settings

I've got a few projects that all use a 'shared_app'. In that shared_app I have a module named `default_settings.py` that contains the settings that are used by *all* projects that have that shared_app.

Folder structure is the usual Django structure:

```
project_dir
 |
 - project_dir
    |
    - settings.py
    - urls.py
    - wsgi.py
 - shared_app
    |
    - default_settings.py
    - ... all other app files ...
 - other_app
 - some_other_app
 - ...other project files....
```

In my `project_dir/settings.py` I have these lines:

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

exec(
    open(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "shared_app", "default_settings.py")).read()
) in globals()

# Below this line - I can use any settings from default_settings.py 

if DEBUG:
    SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE = False
```

The `default_settings.py` files contains things like:

```
DEBUG = is_debug(os.environ.get("DJANGO_DEBUG"))

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get("DJANGO_SECRET_KEY")

SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE = True
```

There are simply too many settings in `default_settings.py` to have something like `from share_app import THIS, THAT, OTHER` There are around 20-30 settings.

Is there a better way to do this? Or am I stuck with that slightly confusing, ugly `exec()` command? Is there anything more 'pythonic'?

Comment: `from somewhere.default_settings import *`? Note that this is not advised normally as you don't know what names are imported but this will work in the case of `settings.py` atleast.

Comment: Yeah, my linter doesn't care for it - but I think this may work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do, if I understood you right:

```
from share_app import *
```

Comment: Looks like that may work - although my linter doesn't care for it much.